# Impossible to roll back to "Use Default" on date fields

Tags: magento

I have just reported a bug to Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=11842) and I was wondering if someone here ever saw this problem and found a solution.

Here is the thing :

For any date type field in product edit page in backend :

1- Switch to a store view

2- Uncheck "Use default" (for a date field)

3- Chose a date

4- Save product and continue edit

5- Recheck "Use default"

6- Save product and continue edit

"Use default" checkbox stays unchecked :(

Field value is empty and editable :(

I've tried several googling and didn't find any answer that works.

Many thanks for sharing I you have a clue.

Comment: Any particular fields? 'Product as New from and to' dates are notionally Global as is 'Special Price from and to', the design tab has 'Active from and to' set to website. Special 'to and from' is not necessarily 'global' - there are store identifiers for those in the db but I have not checked how the attribute is configured on the front end. If you could be more specific on fields that would be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in CE 1.5
Here is how to fix it for previous versions.

Edit app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Datetime.php

Replace

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $_formated = $object->getData($attributeName . '_is_formated');
    if (!$_formated && $object->hasData($attributeName)) {
        try {
            $value = $this->formatDate($object->getData($attributeName));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid date.");
        }
        $object->setData($attributeName, $value);
        $object->setData($attributeName . '_is_formated', true);
    }
}
```

with

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $_formated = $object->getData($attributeName . '_is_formated');
    if (!$_formated && $object->hasData($attributeName)) {
        try {
            $value = $this->formatDate($object->getData($attributeName));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid date.");
        }

        if (is_null($value)) {
            $value = $object->getData($attributeName);
        }            

        $object->setData($attributeName, $value);
        $object->setData($attributeName . '_is_formated', true);
    }
}
```